# How can I duplicate a site without users and nodes?

Tags: 7

I have a full site which has nodes, users, views, organic groups... What I need to do, is with f.e. module 'backup and migrate', take this site named A, into a new server, and keep all logic (content types, views, organic group settings), but have no users at all (except user 1 of course), no nodes at all, actual delete everything, but keep all the functionality of the site.

For instance, if site A has already say 5k users, and 1m nodes, start with the site B with 1 user, and not a single node. How can this be achieved? Is there a module or do I need to run a script into MySQL?

Comment: You can look at drush sql-sanitize (https://drushcommands.com/drush-9x/sql/sql:sanitize/), it may fit your needs.

Comment: very interesting, in the documentation it says: "Sanitize the database by removing or obfuscating user data". But i need also to remove all nodes created, i need to keep the content types, but i need to have them empty. Can the above command achieve this?

Comment: Yes though you may need to customize it.

Comment: thank you, i will just use drush sql:sanitize, hope this will do the job, of removing all content, and all users but user 1, and see what i get.

Answer (score 0):

In drupal 8, this would be no problem thanks to the Configuration API. For drupal 7, it is a bit harder. You should take a look at the [Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) module: this module can save configuration in a module. Then, you can enable that module in a new website (which would create content types, views, etc.).